# Detect if java is run from cron or through shell

Tags: java

How to detect if java is run from cron or through interactive shell.

I need to determine if the script is called by a user (show error message in sys.out) or cron(send error as email)

Comment: Why not make it dependent on a command line switch? Propably easier and less hacky/more robust.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your your crontab job you can pass an additional command line switch like `-Dcron=true` and that you can check inside your java code to branch out your logic.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the stdout and stderr of any job run by cron is sent to the owner of the cronjob in email already.

If you want to handle that explicitly just add a command line option such as `--cron` that is passed to the cron job.  Or more generally `--email=bob@whatever` which allows any invocation to send its output via email.

Comment: if you don't want to flood your inbox with emails, you can send it to some file as well, like <command for your job> > /home/user/cron_output.txt

Answer (score 0):

I would support -D solution as a most portable.

Still, if you need to implement a no-configuration solution, and you're OK to limit yourself to specific flavour of Unix (e.g. Linux), you may walk process tree to find if any of your parents are cron process:

Under Linux, read /proc/self/status:

```
cat /proc/self/status
Name:   bash
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   9872
Pid:    9872
PPid:   9870
...
```

Then, according to PPid entry above, read /proc/9870/status, ... and continue until you reach PPid 1, which is init. If cron nowhere to be found, you're not under cron.

I also pretty sure somewhere under /proc/self you can find a direct specification what console/tty the process is running under (if none, than it must be a daemon, started by cron or not), but I couldn't find it right away.